# Ubuntu Server 18.04: How to use a preinstalled image?

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi

I'm trying to put Ubuntu 18.04 onto a Raspberry Pi 4. As far as I can tell using the [preinstalled server image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/bionic/daily-preinstalled/current/) is the best bet, but I cannot find any resources explaining how to "unpack a preinstalled version of Ubuntu-Server onto a target device." What does this mean, and how can I do it?

Does this just mean that instead of flashing the image to the SD card with a tool like BalenaEtcher, I'm just supposed to copy-paste the download's contents onto the card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, download the server image and then use Balena Etcher to flash the SD card.

To get the latest server image go to:
https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

For installation instructions see:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview

This tutorial suggests using the Raspberry Pi Installer to flash the SD card, but you can also use Balena Etcher.